# Viewing images from google cloud storage?

Tags: storage, gcloud

I have a bunch of images in a google cloud storage bucket, and I want to be able to view them as a group, scroll through them with arrow keys etc. Really minimal interaction. Is there any way to do this right now without downloading all of the images locally (incurring egress)? Some kind of service I can stand up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You're limited to viewing the object names and metadata through gsutil or the storage browser.

**NB** viewing images (e.g. in a browser) involves downloading the image to the browser

A solution may involve your developing e.g. a Cloud Function that turns images (as they're uploaded) to Cloud Storage buckets into thumbnails (smaller) that could then be rendered into pages of HTML for browsing. But, this does not exist as part of Google Cloud Storage *and* it would still involve downloading the (albeit) smaller images for viewing.